# Linux AWK Programming

Tags: awk

I am trying the sort through mail log files using awk. My goal is to determine which emails had a delay longer than 10 seconds. The format of the log file displays the delays in `delay=xxxx` I have came up with:

```
awk '/delay/ { if($9 >=10) print}' filename
```

When I run this command it returns all the entries with the word delay and does not just give the delays that are greater than 10 seconds.

Please Help

Comment: Show us some sample lines from the log file for which the code fails.

Comment: post a few lines from your log to avoid confusing

Answer (score 0):

Here is a sample *mogfile*:

```
$ cat mog
... the log file displays the delays in delay=11 ...
... the log file displays the delays in delay=9 ...
```

and the script:

```
$ awk '/delay/{split($9,a,"=");if(a[2]>=10)print}' mog
... the log file displays the delays in delay=11 ...
```

Comment: I attempted the awk '/delay/{split($9,a,"=");if(a[2]>=10)print}'... it still displays all the listed logs in the file that contains the word "delay"

Comment: @KeithBoigegrain How about you post some lines of the said log and we'll see.